# IOS7 UITableView settings app style

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a UITableView that looks like iOS 7 settings bags, with UISwitches, text fields, etc. I set up my user interface on storyboard by dragging a UITableView in my UIViewcontroller and adding stuff in the cells. When I run the app, the only result is a blank UItableView...

This is the tipe of setting:

[image]

EDIT:
Not really relevant but to the question but...
Does anyone know what king of color the one they use below the UITableView?

Comment: Dragging stuff into a UITableView in your storyboard won't show when you run it in simulator unless you add the code for it to show (like the data source & delegate methods).

Comment: Which is your problem, blank UITableView, or adding extra UI to the cells?

Comment: Or is it figuring out the color to use for the line/background of those regions (looks like (200,199,204) for the edge and (239,239,239) according to the color picker)?

Comment: The problem is blank UITableView, the class is the normal class UITableView not a custom class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols and connect them to your table view. Otherwise it will not show you anything, as you can't build it in the Interface Builder. That works only for design, but not for content.

Look at the protocols and their required methods:
[UITableViewDataSource Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
[UITableViewDelegate Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

After that is implemented, you have to connect your table view with the data source and delegate in the Interface builder.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question: "That works only for design, but not for content". The design is what I care about, not the content.

Comment: But you will not see the design without any content. :) You have to implement it, otherwise you'll not see anything.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set Content type to static cells in the tableview settings in storyboard.

You can now add more custom cells after that and you wont have to write a single line of code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Till. Appreciate it.